# Do quantiles (percentiles) have to be "directly" contained within the data?

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following numbers:

```
library(stats)
set.seed(123)

a <- rnorm(20, 20, 100)

a  
#  [1]  -36.047565   -3.017749  175.870831   27.050839   32.928774
#  [6]  191.506499   66.091621 -106.506123  -48.685285  -24.566197
# [11]  142.408180   55.981383   60.077145   31.068272  -35.584113
# [16]  198.691314   69.785048 -176.661716   90.135590  -27.279141
```

I took the 80% quantile of these numbers :

```
quantile(a, 0.8)
#      80% 
# 100.5901
```

**My Question:** Is R calculating this correctly? For example, the number `100.5901`  is not "directly" contained in the above set of numbers (i.e. `100.5901` is between `min(a)` and `max(a)`, but the number `100.5901` does not appear in the 20 numbers in the above list).

Thus, do quantiles, i.e. percentiles of the data correspond to an exact element within the data (e.g. the closest element to `100.5901` is `106.50`)  - or can a percentiles correspond to a number that is not directly in the list (e.g. a number between `90.13` and `106.50`)?

Comment: It is the 80th percentile cut off.  According to the documentation `quantile returns estimates of underlying distribution quantiles based on one or two order statistics from the supplied elements in x at probabilities in probs.`.

Comment: Quantiles do not need to reside in the data, there is some "interpolation" of sorts with calculations. The closest exception that I can think of is `median`: its value will reside in the original data if there are an odd number of values, but if there are an even number then the median value will be the average of the two center-most values, which may not be an actual value resident in the original data.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want the minimum value that actually appears in your data and is at or above the quantile mark, you can use `min(a[a>=quantile(a,0.8)]) ` . This gets you 142.4082. It would be incorrect, however, to say that this 142.4082 is the 80th percentile threshold.